# CSS Flexbox issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

Attempting to show a search input and button (grouped) next to a button using flexbox.

```
<div class="border-r border-gray-900 flex px-6 py-3 w-64">
  <div class="flex flex-grow">
      <input class="border flex-grow w-full" type="search" />
      <button class="bg-blue-500 p-3">search</button>
  </div>
  <button class="bg-blue-500 p-3">+</button>
</div>
```

For some reason this works nicely in chrome, but the content overlaps in firefox.

How can I fix this to work in firefox?
Or is there another workaround that I could use to get the same effect?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/QbrWi7mSxm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add min-width: 1px; to input field

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working the same in firefox and Chrome:

```
<div class="border-r border-gray-900 flex px-6 py-3 w-max">
      <input class="border" type="search" />
      <button class="bg-blue-500 p-3">search</button>
      <button class="bg-blue-500 p-3">+</button>
</div>
```

and it looks like yours I think, the only difference is that the input gets a bit longer, but you can fix that with `w-` classes